# what's different between RACK_ENV and RAILS_ENV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get the current enviroment of my rails application.
But I don't konw what's different between RACK_ENV and RAILS_ENV?
Who can help me?

Why sometimes RACK_ENV is empty, but RAILS_ENV has value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rails applications uses `RAILS_ENV`. Other Rack-based applications use `RACK_ENV`. If you have a Rails application, ignore `RACK_ENV`.

EDIT: The other answer is more correct.

Answer (score 32):

You can use RACK_ENV as well as RAILS_ENV except for RAILS_ENV is prior to RACK_ENV.

[rails/rails.rb at b0b4b176b0e061a4f03ddce669637b7d6c37aa33 · rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b0b4b176b0e061a4f03ddce669637b7d6c37aa33/railties/lib/rails.rb#L70)

Comment: Finally, someone who uses a line of code as reference and don't just throw in the link to the file in the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

```
def set_environment
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= options[:environment]
end
```

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] is from options

```
def options
  merged_options = @use_default_options ? default_options.merge(@options) : @options
  merged_options.reject { |k, v| @ignore_options.include?(k) }
end
```

if default rails server, environment is from default options

```
def default_options
  environment  = ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
  default_host = environment == 'development' ? 'localhost' : '0.0.0.0'

  {
    :environment => environment,
    :pid         => nil,
    :Port        => 9292,
    :Host        => default_host,
    :AccessLog   => [],
    :config      => "config.ru"
  }
end
```

so, ENV['RACK_ENV'] has default value 'development'